# WPF- Loop all dynamically created textBoxs inside dockPanels inside stackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm creating table of `TextBox` controls.

I have two buttons to add rows and columns dynamically.

My code works as follows.

I have a predefined `StackPanel` with a name *TheStackpanel*, which I'm creating new `DockPanel` dynamically inside for each new rows and I'm docking dynamically created `TextBox` controls inside the created `DockPanel`s.

What I want is to loop all text boxes that were created. For example to read text out of them.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (var EachDockPanel in TheStackpanel.Children)
{
    foreach (var EachTextBox in EachDockPanel/*.something I don't know*/)
    {
        EachTextBox.Text += "Hi" //For Example
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not asked a question. And, dockpanel Has children property you need to use at the inner foreach loop.

Comment: I want to Loop the TextBoxes using (for each) for example. I wrote this code to show the logic that I want and how does my code work. but I don't know to to make it work. (EachDockPanel) didn't suggest me children property!!

Comment: EachDockPanel does not suggest children because you define this as a var.  Use DockPanel instead.  or, if you may have children that are not DockPanels,, Use the var version and then provide a statement that casts the var to a DockPanel using the "as DockPanel" method of casting - this will either cast to a DockPanel or provide a null - this avoids the InvalidCast exception.  Once you have a DockPanel, you can access the children.

Comment: Thank you dear too much, appreciate it. I defined the  DockPanels in the first foreach statement  and TextBox in the inner foreach statement rather than var and that worked